# Vue 3.0: How to add an addEventListener to the parent element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I don't know how to add an `addEventListener` to the parent in Vue 3.x.

I found out that you can get the parent by using this code:

```
import { getCurrentInstance, onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
    console.log(getCurrentInstance().parent)
})
```

But how do I get the `HTML`-element so I can add the listener to it?

---

I am currently trying to migrate my code from Vue 2.x to Vue 3.x.

In Vue 2.x you could easily add an EventListener to a **specific** element:

```
mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 50));
},
beforeDestroy() {
    this.$el.removeEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 15));
},
```

**Very important**: I do not want to add the listener to the `window` element or `document` element of the browser.

I want to know the scroll state of a particular element. The scroll state of the browser may not even have moved. Have a look at this picture:

[image]

As you can see, you can only scroll inside the div-box where you see the placeholder text.

**Now to my problem:**

I'm using `swiper.js` to generate many slides next to each other.

The structure of the code looks something like this:

```
<SwiperWrapper>
    <SwiperSlide> 
        <FirstSlide />
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>
        <SecondSlide />
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>
        <ThirdSlide />
    </SwiperSlide>
</SwiperWrapper>
```

`<SwiperSlide>` is the element where I want to have an EventListener on scroll, because this is the only `div` element that is scrollable due to `overflow-y: auto;`.

But because `<SwiperSlide>` is a component from `swiper.js`, I have to add the EventListener inside **each** slide element (e.g. `<FirstSlide>`, `<SecondSlide>` etc.)

Here is an example to understand my issue better. If you scroll down to script, you will see how I did it in the past.

https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-navigation-vue-forked-vem09w?file=/src/FirstSlide.vue

Comment: Have you tried adding an `id` to the `<SwiperSlide>` and refer to it in the actual slide element with `document.getElementById('someID')`?

Comment: @Amats Good point, I thought about it, but I don't like having to create the ID manually and then to send the information through a prop 

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-parent-access-8hto2d)

The `addEventListener` function is available on the parent's `subTree.el`.

Like:

```
const parentHTML = getCurrentInstance().parent.subTree.el
parentHTML.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'))
```

So you can do:

```
data: () =>({
    parent: null
}),
mounted() {
    this.parent = getCurrentInstance().parent.subTree.el;
    this.parent.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 50));
},
beforeDestroy() {
    this.parent.removeEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 15));
},
```